# Why doesn't typescript infer the correct type when using an index signature on a generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given the following types:

```
type DataNode = {
  value: string;
};

type Data<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: DataNode };
```

and this class and method:

```
class Reader<T> {
  read(data: Data<T>, key: keyof Data<T>) {
    const node = data[key];
    // ...
  }
}
```

The type of `node` is determined by typescript to be `Data<T>[keyof T]`

I am expecting it to be `DataNode`. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-index-types?file=index.ts

Comment: Your code works as expected https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOA5A9gE2gXigbwFBSFQBucANgK4QBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDceAvt3qEiwEcADwAVAHxRsOKAG0A1hBBQ2UZSBQAzKOIC6AflrxEqDFD548AYzJw6dKACUIcDIwnT8RKIzdoABRoIiYiXgA0Giq0mjpQgaZiUgCUKbgEvkQ2KKwMUKzoWFAhiEoq+txZRP7AFIysBUWZ1QD0rVAAdN0tlrzWOXnAJaHCiKJycOw0UAAsAEyW0rJQUzNypJQzAOTzAMzblpb8g-mq2KwQAO4uARCek9O0C0uBKSe5+QAeMlAgnf53IFHusSOQqLRdgcjjwots1tt3lB2mNkEUoAAfKAUVgYbRsCBoIA

Comment: It does indeed - I thought it didn't due to the intellisense not showing `DataNode`, and my real world problem which used a union type so it wasn't clear what was going on. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are interested in Smarter Type Alias Preservation. See here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2/#smarter-type-alias-preservation    This is new feature in TS 4.2, i think it does not show `DataNode` type because of generic